# How to implement the code in after function?

Tags: javascript, function, callback

How to implement the code after function?
It should invoke function only after the third time

```js
function after(count, funct) {
  // code...
}

var called = function () {
  console.log("hello");
};

var afterCalled = after(3, called);
afterCalled(); // --> nothing is printed
afterCalled(); // --> nothing is printed
afterCalled(); // --> "hello" is printed
```

Comment: Did you try some approach yourself? Please show us your attempt.

Answer (score 2):

You could return a function which decrements the counter and if zero it calls the handed over function.

```js
function after(count, funct) {
    return function () {
        if (!--count) funct();
    };
}

var called = function () {
  console.log("hello");
};

var afterCalled = after(3, called);
afterCalled(); // --> nothing is printed
console.log('.')
afterCalled(); // --> nothing is printed
console.log('.')
afterCalled(); // --> "hello" is printed
console.log('.')
afterCalled(); // --> nothing is printed
```

Comment: What would happen on a fourth call?

Comment: @Bergi, nothing.